# "Hat full of napalm" or "Heart full of napalm"?

Tags: song-lyrics

[Here is a youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDNzQ3CXspU) the song in question *[Search and Destroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_and_Destroy_(The_Stooges_song))*, released by the Stooges on the album [Raw Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_Power).

The web tells me the line is:

> I'm a streetwalking cheetah with a heart full of napalm

But I always thought the line was:

> I'm a streetwalking *cheater* with a *hat* full of napalm?

*(On the track, he seems to pronounce it as "hat" requires a Boston accent if it's actually "heart"—Iggy is from Michigan;)*

**Q: Do the lyrics posted on the internet come from a textual source, such as liner notes, or is it possible inaccuracies have been introduced and codified by the internet?**

[Search and Destroy Lyrics as posted on the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=search%20and%20destroy%20stooges%20lyrics&oq=search%20and%20destroy%20stooges%20lyrics&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l3.7655j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's "I'm a streetwalking cheetah", and "heart full of napalm", as per [this interview](https://books.google.ca/books?id=UbHeAQAAQBAJ&pg=PT174&lpg=PT174&dq=I%20used%20to%20walk%20around%20London,%20through%20the%20park%20and%20stuff,%20with%20this%20leopard%20jacket%20I%20had,%20a%20cheetah-skin%20jacket%20actually-%20it%20had%20a%20big%20cheetah%20on%20the%20back-and%20all%20the%20old%20men%20in%20London%20would%20drive%20by%20in%20their%20cars%20and%20they%E2%80%99d%20stop%20and%20try%20to%20cruise%20me.%20All%20I%20liked%20to%20do%20was%20walk%20around%20the%20streets%20with%20a%20heart%20full%20of%20napalm.%20I%20always%20thought%20Heart%20Full%20of%20Soul%20was%20a%20good%20song%20so%20I%20thought,%20What%E2%80%99s%20my%20heart%20full%20of?%20I%20decided%20it%20was%20basically%20full%20of%20napalm.&source=bl&ots=XgBYdJ-FSj&sig=O6Auwlr2ryxqQKXRgEUPV4pKTnc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBlc3b3e7VAhVL6IMKHRnwAaQQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=I%20used%20to%20walk%20around%20London%2C%20through%20the%20park%20and%20stuff%2C%20with%20this%20leopard%20jacket%20I%20had%2C%20a%20cheetah-skin%20jacket%20actually-%20it%20had%20a%20big%20cheetah%20on%20the%20back-and%20all%20the%20old%20men%20in%20London%20would%20drive%20by%20in%20their%20cars%20and%20they%E2%80%99d%20stop%20and%20try%20to%20cruise%20me.%20All%20I%20liked%20to%20do%20was%20walk%20around%20the%20streets%20with%20a%20heart%20full%20of%20napalm.%20I%20always%20thought%20Heart%20Full%20of%20Soul%20was%20a%20good%20song%20so%20I%20thought%2C%20What%E2%80%99s%20my%20heart%20full%20of%3F%20I%20decided%20it%20was%20basically%20full%20of%20napalm.&f=false) with Iggy Pop from *Please Kill Me: The Uncensored History of Punk*.

Iggy Pop says: "I used to walk around London, through the park and stuff, with this leopard jacket I had, a cheetah-skin jacket actually- it had a big cheetah on the back-and all the old men in London would drive by in their cars and they’d stop and try to cruise me.
All I liked to do was walk around the streets with a heart full of napalm. I always thought Heart Full of Soul was a good song so I thought, What’s my heart full of?
I decided it was basically full of napalm."

So the Internet is correct in their listing of the lyrics.

Comment: That explains the "street walking" part.  Thanks for definitively answering this question that has been nagging me for some years now!